# NGINX How to make HTTP Basic Auth pages Gzip enable

Tags: nginx, gzip, http-auth

Here are my gzip setttings:

```
##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;

  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  # Don't compress anything under 256 bytes
  gzip_min_length     256;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable  'MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)';
  gzip_types
   application/atom+xml
   application/javascript
   application/json
   application/rss+xml
   application/vnd.ms-fontobject
   application/x-font-ttf
   application/x-font-opentype
   application/x-font-truetype
   application/x-javascript
   application/x-web-app-manifest+json
   application/xhtml+xml
   application/xml
   font/eot
   font/opentype
   font/otf
   image/svg+xml
   image/x-icon
   image/vnd.microsoft.icon
   text/css
   text/plain
   text/javascript
   text/x-component;
```

> curl -IL https://example.com
>
> HTTP/2 401
>
> server: nginx
>
> date: Fri, 28 Dec 2018 14:09:26 GMT
>
> content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> content-length: 7326
>
> www-authenticate: Basic realm="Privacy Enabled"
>
> etag: "5c262af8-1c9e"

As you see the page is not enabled by gzip

How can I make 401 pages gzip enabled?

Comment: I see in gzip_types `text/html` is missing. Can you add that to the list?

Comment: In case you do not wish to gzip text/html, change the content type of 401 response.

Comment: Any update on @fiveelements comments?

Comment: The mimeType text/html is missing, so its getting excluded, 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

In your curl example the type is `text/html` which isn't in your `gzip_types`.

Add `text/html` to `gzip_types` and it should work.